# How to remove before portion of string in php ?

Tags: php, jquery

```
$keyword = "ios-developer-jobs-in-noida";
$city = strstr($keyword, 'in-');
echo $city;
```

I have a string in my URL now I want to remove `ios-developer-jobs-in-` but using `strstr($keyword, 'in-');` it shows `in-noida`. I want only `noida`. So, How can I resolve this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: `substr(str, 3)`

Comment: it shows `-developer-jobs-in-noida` @u_mulder but I want only `noida`

Comment: Then think a little and maybe you should use `$city` in `substr`?

Comment: try: list ($msgid, $city)=split('in-', $keyword);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this if character comes after last -

```
substr($foo, (strrpos($foo, '-', -1))+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```html
<?php
$keyword = "ios-developer-jobs-in-noida";
$city = explode("-",substr($keyword, strpos($keyword,'in-')));
echo $city[1];
?>
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

```
$keyword = "ios-developer-jobs-in-noida";
$city = explode("-",substr($keyword, strpos($keyword,'in-')));
echo $city[1];
```

Comment: actually `ios-developer-jobs-in-noida` this is in my URL parameters and it is dynamic @Roshan Patil

Comment: You need to explain in your question EXACTLY how much your input syring may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Ypu could use strrpos and substr

```
$keyword = "ios-developer-jobs-in-noida";

$city =   substr(str, (-1)*strrpos($keyword, "-"))
```

Or explode and end()

```
$myArray = explode("-",$keyword);
$city =  end($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how much your string may vary or if `-in-` is guaranteed to exist, but this will work on your sample input.

```
$keyword = "ios-developer-jobs-in-noida";

echo explode('-in-', $keyword, 2)[1];
```

Use `-in-` as your delimiter and cap the explosion at 2 elements.  Use the 2nd element.